# Why do we need concept of general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

suppose we have second order ODE, that is $y''+ p(x)y'+ q(x)y = 0 $.
Then let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be solutions of this ODE. Its obvious that $c_1y_1 +c_2y_2$ will also be solution, where we call this form general solution.

**Now my questions are:**
Why do we need general solution if $y_n$ alone satisfies the ODE?
Is the concept of general solution consequence of initial value problem?

Comment: 1) General solutions come without call: whenever you haven't specified IVP or BVP, you'll have not a single solution, but a parametric family of solutions 2) For linear ODEs it is quite easy to find some particular solutions (as in many other ODEs, frankly speaking). But the power (and, at the same time, the weakness ) of linear ODEs is that having enough good (linear independent) particular solutions is enough to infer the information about the whole solution set of this linear ODE. And to solve IVP in particular.